# How can I move to the UK with my child

Tags: united-kingdom, resident-permit

As a primary carer of am EU minor child do I have rights to apply for permit in UK, i leave in Italian residence permit holder and I would like to move to UK by September with a family permit Visa 
Am a citizen of Nigeria with Italian residence card     indefinite leave  not Article 10, the EU child is my daughter with which I had with EU unmarried partner so I have a EU permit Visa 6months

Comment: Your question isn’t very clear. What is your citizenship? Do you mean you have an Italian residence permit? If so, is it an Article 10 permit https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card? What is your family relationship to the child?

Comment: Is the child a citizen of the UK?  Are there any other EU citizen relatives in the child's life?

Comment: What is the underlying purpose of the move? Eg schooling for the child? https://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2004:158:0077:0123:en:PDF

Comment: Finding definitive information doesn’t appear to be easy. This report https://ecas.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/ECAS-Study-on-Freedom-of-Movement-in-the-EU.pdf
4.15. ...“a young child can take advantage of the rights of free movement and residence. [ ] ...and as long as they have sufficient resources and healthcare cover, they can reside in the host Member State. [ ] such circumstances, those same provisions allow a parent who is that minor’s primary carer to reside with the child in the host Member State”379. Thus, non-EU carers of EU minors derive residence rights from their children...